# Independent throwing of different color balls into bins

Tags: probability

1. I have $3$ black balls to throw into $5$ bins. Each throw is independent. What is the probability at least $1$ bin has $2$ or more black balls?
2. I have $3$ black balls and $3$ white balls throw into $5$ bins. Each throw is independent. What is the probability at least $1$ bin has $2$ or more same color ball?

I had a complicated solution for the (1) question, but not sure it's a reasonable solution. First, the probability of any giving bin having $2$ or more black ball is $$\frac{{3 \choose 2}\cdot 4^1+{3 \choose 3}}{5^3}= 13/125$$
Then, there are $5$ bins. If $13/125*5$, it will come up as $13/25$. But I am not sure the reasoning of multiple by $5$ is plausible.

Comment: "then the 3rd ball must go into one of the two occupied bins (3/5 chance).". Do you mean 2/5? Also, can you elaborate the 2nd part?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Let us find the prob that no bin has 2 or more balls. It does not matter where the 1st ball goes. The 2nd ball must go into any of the 4 empty bins (prob 4/5), and the 3rd ball must go into any of the 3 empty bins (prob 3/5). So prob 12/25 of no bin with 2 or more balls, and hence 13/25 of getting at least 1 bin with 2 or more balls.

(2) If there is no bin with 2 or more of the same colour, then there is no bin with 2 or more white - prob 12/25 from part (1) - and there is no bin with 2 or more black - also prob 12/25. Hence 144/625. So prob 481/625 that there is a bin with 2 or more of the same colour

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I had a complicated solution for the (1) question before I submit the question.But not sure it's correct, so that I asked. First, the probability of any giving bin having 2 or more black ball is $\frac{{3 \choose 2}*4^1+1}{5^3}$ = 13/125. Then, there are 5 bins. If 13/125*5, it will come up as 13/25, but I am not sure multiple by 5 is reasonable.

Comment: You should transfer the work you are showing from the comments to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

$(1):$ You might like to  treat it as a $5$ sided die thrown $3$ times to put it into a familiar category:

Favourable *patterns* :

$3-0-0-0-0:$
$\left[\binom51\;\text{ways to choose the die faces}\right]\times\left[\frac{3!}{3!}\text{ ways to sequence them}\right]= 5$

$2-1-0-0-0:$
$\left[\binom51\binom41\;\text{ways to choose the die faces}\right]\times\left[\frac{3!}{2!1!} \text{ ways to sequence them}\right] = 60$

so $Pr = \dfrac{5+60}{5^3} = \dfrac{65}{125} = \dfrac{13}{25}$

$(2)$ is simply $1$ - P(neither color fulfills criteria) $= 1 - \dfrac{12}{25}\times\dfrac{12}{25}$